# How to install/uninstall python 3.x to specific path?

Tags: linux-mint, python3

I've installed `python 3.5.2` on my system, but it was divided between folders in `/usr/local`, some went to `lib`, some to `bin`. I know why this is for packages, which are installed by `apt-get`, but I would prefer to install packages (which are not from package manager) to one directory.

Can this be done? And how can we properly uninstall this kind of packages?

**Note:**
when I installed `textlive2015`, from the `tug.org` it all installed in one directory `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: downloaded from python.org the package, unpacked, run ./configure, make install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and extract the source code from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Open a terminal in the directory where you extracted the code.

```
./configure --prefix=/directory/to/install
make
sudo make install
```

Refer to `./configure --help` for full details. If you want to install different python versions at the same time, use `make altinstall` or `--exec-prefix` option.

To uninstall the previous version that you installed with make, you could try to find and delete all the python directories in `/usr/local` or use `checkinstall` (recommended) to make a deb package to reinstall and uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
cd /path/to/python/source
./configure
sudo checkinstall -D --fstrans=no make install
sudo dpkg -i Python-3.5.2.deb
sudo dpkg -r Python-3.5.2
```

Comment: I think it will work, but how do I uninstall the one which is already installed?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include uninstall information.